# How do I move files in a S3 bucket while keeping the folders and not deleting them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

In S3, I have a folder A that only has 1 file.

I want to move that file to folder B, as in copy the file from A to B & then deleting it from A.

However, the CDK is also deleting the A folder when it deletes the file. I want to keep both folders.

Why is it deleting the folders and how can I tell the CDK not to?

Comment: The CDK is not deleting the A folder. It never physically existed. Ideally you would not need the A folder to exist after moving `A/file.png` to `B/file.png` but if you really do then you would have to write an object representing the A folder (which would mean uploading a zero-sized object whose key was `A/`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you see folders in the AWS console, there are no real 'folders' in Amazon S3. They are just simulated based on the object key containing a folder prefix followed by a forward slash. For example, the presence of an object with a prefix of `A/` represents a logical folder named `A`.

After deleting the only object left with the 'folder' in its object key, there are no more objects left with the ‘folder’ in their keys so the ‘folder’ also disappears along with the object.

**You will have to recreate the 'folder' yourself**.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html) on how to manually create folders i.e. what the ‘Create folder’ option in the AWS console does:

> When you use the Amazon S3 console to create a folder, Amazon S3 creates a 0-byte object with a key that's set to the folder name that you provided. For example, if you create a folder named photos in your bucket, the Amazon S3 console creates a 0-byte object with the key photos/. The console creates this object to support the idea of folders.
>
> The Amazon S3 console treats all objects that have a forward slash (/) character as the last (trailing) character in the key name as a folder (for example, examplekeyname/). You can't upload an object that has a key name with a trailing / character by using the Amazon S3 console. However, you can upload objects that are named with a trailing / with the Amazon S3 API by using the AWS CLI, AWS SDKs, or REST API.

Comment: This isn't quite what happens in the general case. There is simply an object e.g. with key of `dogs/snoopy.png` but there is no zero-sized object with the key `dogs/`. After you delete `dogs/snoopy.png`, Amazon S3 doesn't "recognise that there is no more need for the 0-byte object - or 'folder' - and removes it." That doesn't happen at all, and it certainly wouldn't happen automatically. The only time the zero-sized `dogs/` object exists is if *you* create it. That can happen in many ways, but the most common is if the user chose the 'Create folder' option in the S3 console.

Comment: @jarmod I believe OP was talking in abstract ways, from the point of view of the user. The "folder" is indeed not an object, but it is still a concept that exists in the console. That is probably what they're referring to.

Comment: @gshpychka yes, the folder logically exists (inferred from the keys of existing objects) but it does not physically exist in the typical case (and in this specific case). The answer here suggests the latter and that S3 auto-creates it and auto-deletes it, which is misleading.

Comment: It does auto-create and delete the logical concept of the folder in the console. I believe that's what they're referring to.

Comment: But you're right, it can be read both ways and should probably be clarified.

Comment: @jarmod I understand this could be read in both ways, I’ll edit the answer now to reflect what I mean more carefully ; I was referring to the create folder option like you say however as the OP mentions CDK, I should’ve been clearer

Comment: @jarmod does the edit make it clearer from your POV?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks for updating. I made a couple of minor clarifications, hope that's ok. Yes, this is good now.